# RegEnumKey always returns error ERROR_MORE_DATA

Tags: c, registry, mingw-w64

The code below always returns error 234 (ERROR_MORE_DATA). I completely stuck on it. Cant even imagine where is the mistake.

I have tried to extend keyName to size 327680 chars, this does not effect on the behavior of the code.

```c
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
  HKEY  list;
  char  keyName[32768];
  long  keyNameSize = sizeof(keyName) - 1;
  char* path = "Software\\Microsoft";

  if (RegOpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, path, &list))
  {
    if (GetLastError() == ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)
    {
      printf("access denied\n");
    }

    else
    {
      printf("failed to open key\n");
    }

    return;
  }

  printf("regopenkey success\n");

  long result = RegEnumKey(list, 0, keyName, keyNameSize);

  printf("reg enum key (result code: %d) (keyName: %s) (keyNameSize: %d)\n",
    result, keyName, keyNameSize);

  if (result)
  {
    if (GetLastError() == ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)
    {
      printf("access denied\n");
    }

    else
    {
      printf("failed to enumerate key\n");
    }

    return;
  }

  printf("regenumkey success\n");
}
```

The expected output result is:

```
regopenkey success
reg enum key (result code: 0) (keyName: Something) (keyNameSize: 32767)
regenumkey success
```

The actual output result is:

```
regopenkey success
reg enum key (result code: 234) (keyName: ) (keyNameSize: 32767)
failed to enumerate key
```

Comment: The documentation says `Note  This function is provided only for compatibility with 16-bit versions of Windows. Applications should use the RegEnumKeyEx function.` You may wish to consider that advice.

Comment: Your code works as written if the size of the keyName array is reduced to 256. I arrived at that size by reading this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry-element-size-limits.

Comment: Thank you, it solves the problem.